# Add an Individual Field to Every Page of an SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

### Goal

I'd like to be able to add an individual field (or *multiple fields*) to an SSRS report *outside* of a tablix.

Basically, per the example in the screenshot below, I'm attempting to create an invoice template wherein a page would be generated for each company we wish to bill.

**On each page would reside the** `tablix` **containing the invoice details** (e.g., type of product, amount owed, etc.) **as well as the individual** `fields` **such as invoice number** (which I can pull in from the dataset).

[image]

FYI, in case you're wondering: the reason I wouldn't include these fields in the tablix referenced (or in another tablix) is just for layout purposes. The template we've designed has fields like ID, invoice number, first name, etc. in specific/different areas of the page.

### Steps Taken:

After establishing the `data source` and `dataset`, I can add one of these fields by dragging-and-dropping it onto the page but, when previewing the output, **the field only shows up on the first page**.

I've perused relevant results from S.O. as well as TechNet, etc. but, perhaps due to my limited knowledge of the terminology, I'm just not finding that for which I'm looking. Perhaps, even still, this type of functionality that existed in Crystal Reports just isn't available in SSRS. I doubt that, though.

Thanks in advance,
- JH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try putting the textboxes and tablix within a list and group on the InvoiceNumber and then in the properties for the list you can set that there should be a page break between groups.  This should fix your issue with the textboxes not showing on each invoice.

Lists are helpful so you can group multiple elements together.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I was reviewing 2 or 3 textbooks and a vast plethora of Bing searches to find what I was looking for and I don't think I stumbled on the "list" feature once. Great information. Thanks so much!